# Amazon Lex V2 Lambda not progressing to next slot

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-lex

I have a LEX V2 bot configured, which has two slots and a confirmation slot. The two slots ask for `dateFrom` and `dateTo`. Now I have a Lambda that I use for fulfilment but also needs to fire on every single event. After the initial utterance, the Lambda takes the `event.proposedNextState.dialogAction.slotToElicit` and returns that inside `dialogAction.slotToElicit` along with `dialogAction.type` set to "Delegate". Now that works fine, however after providing the `dateFrom` value, even though the lambda responds with

```js
{
  sessionState: { dialogAction: { type: 'Delegate', slotToElicit: 'dateTo' } }
}
```

the next slot is not `dateTo`, but rather `dateFrom` again. Anyone has any ideas why it might not work like that? I don't understand why it is like that, maybe I am supposed to send a different type on dialog action? Below is the full Lambda function which handles events that are of type `DialogCodeHook`:

```js
const response: LexResponse = {
    sessionState: {
      dialogAction: {
        type: LexDialogActionType.Delegate,
        slotToElicit: event.proposedNextState.dialogAction.slotToElicit,
      },
    },
  };
  console.log("EVENT", event);
  console.log("RESPONSE", response);
  callback(null, response);
```

Comment: Hi there, try `ElicitSlot` instead.

Comment: @Reegz so I actually tried that, but that does not work either - the same thing happens where it just gets stuck in a loop :/ I managed to get it work by sending `intent` along with `dialogAction` in `sessionState` - but now I have the problem of the last event which should have been a `FulfillmentCodeHook` actually just returning a `DialogCodeHook` with `confirmationState: "Confirmed"` after the confirmation prompt (which I guess is fine because I know they've confirmed it and I can run the fulfillment function but it's still weird

Answer (score 0):

Intent is mandatory in the Lambda response if dialogAction.type=Delegate.
However, AWS documentation about response format is misleading. It says "intent – The name of the intent that Amazon Lex V2 should use". Actually, it's a structure. Set it to event.sessionState.intent.

Although not mandatory, consider forwarding sessionAttributes too.